# VB.NET Clear Datagridview

Tags: vb.net

[image]I have a datagridview that when i open it it fill's with my database table, but if the database table is empty i want to open my dgv default, not the older one with the database table
Hope someone could help me

Comment: You don't *open* a DataGridView, you *open* (Show) a Form that hosts a DGV. You're probably using default instances of forms. Post your code, so it's more clear.

Comment: look,  i have a query above, after i do and if rows.count > 0 put the table values into the dgv, and else i want to put my dgv to default

Comment: You don't have a Form? Are you showing a DGV out of thin air? Of course you have a Form. If your datatable is empty, just set the DataSource to `Nothing`. An interesting point is *when* this happens. Btw, you need to post code, not images of it.

Comment: oh ok i see yes of course i have a form, and yes i already tried that and the dgv stay blank

Comment: When you set the DataSource to null (`Nothing`) or an empty DataTable, the DGV is reset to the layout defined at design time. A `NewRow` is shown if `AllowUsersToAddRows = true`. That's all. If you have added Columns in code, then you won't see anything, unless you add the Columns again.

Comment: yes, i want to show the dgv at design time, not the one that i am creating in the code above

Comment: Then don't clear the Columns, just set a `[DataGridViewColumn].DataPropertyName` to the corresponding Column of your DataTable.

Comment: i don't  know what dataproerty name is, are you saying that i have to define all columns name like above ?

Comment: How are you setting `Name` and `HeaderText` if you don't know what Columns you have in your DataTable? Anyway, it doesn't really matter. If you want to define a default layout, design that layout in code, in a method that you can call to reset the DGV to a *default* state. I'd avoid setting the Height of the NewRow. If you don't like the default gray-ish background, set a different color.

Comment: so i don't need my dgv design ?

Comment: Not if you clear it each time and you don't close the Form (because you don't have one :) Unless the Form is actually your starting Form, so closing it may not be advisable. If that's the case, as already described, build a method that recreates the layout of your DGV. You can take the auto-generated code from .Designer.vb and replicate it in another method.